# Using awk with ssh

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, awk

I am trying to run a command remotely, this is what i have

`ssh host-name "find ~/dir1/dir2/ -name blah\* -exec zgrep -nc pattern \{\} \; > /tmp/temp_file ; awk 'n<$0 {n=$0}END{print n}' /tmp/temp_file"`

This gives me `awk: (FILENAME=temp_file FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted`

The command runs successfully if run on the host locally. Is this due to the way shell parses the command being passed inside the ssh? I tried escaping the /es in the file path and it still gives the same error. I think im missing something very basic but could zero down on it. Would appreciate some help, Thanks.

Comment: Why are you writing to a temp file, rather than piping the `find` output to `awk`?

Comment: Im just starting to learn awk and this my first time using it, possible that what you are suggesting is a better approach, but i just went for a solution easier to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `$0` gets expanded locally because the command is quoted with `"`

You probably want to escape it as `\$0`

I would also use a pipe to avoid the temp file, and as a personal preference use `xargs` instead of the `-exec` predicate of `find`

Also, `grep`'s `-n` option does nothing when `-c` is used.

I think this should be equivalent:

`ssh host-name "find ~/dir1/dir2/ -name blah\* | xargs zgrep -c | awk 'n<\$0 {n=\$0}END{print n}'"`

Or, without `awk`, so no need to escape its arguments:

`ssh host-name "find ~/dir1/dir2/ -name blah\* | xargs zgrep -c | sort -n | tail -1`

Comment: yeah, that worked. But the same command when run locally worked with out the escapes for $0. Can you please explain the need to escape $0?

Comment: Because you have a string like `"... '$0' ... "` which gets expanded by the local shell to `" ... '/bin/sh' ..."` before the `ssh` command even gets run. When you run the command locally you don't surround it in `"` characters, so you have `... '$0' ...` and shell variables do not get expanded inside `'` quotes